# How can I properly remove an OverlayEntry in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my main widget tree, I have a `GestureDetector` that when tapped, will launch an Overlay as follows:

```
          OverlayState? _overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
          _overlayState?.insert(
              OverlayEntry(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return ShowNotificationIcon();
            },
          )
          );
```

`SnowNotificationIcon` is actually a `StatefulWidget` that houses the guts of the Overlay:

```
class ShowNotificationIcon extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const ShowNotificationIcon({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShowNotificationIconState createState() => _ShowNotificationIconState();
}

class _ShowNotificationIconState extends ConsumerState<ShowNotificationIcon> {

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  void dispose(){
    super.dispose();
  }

  Positioned theDropDown(){
    return
      Positioned(
        top: 50.0,
        left: 50.0,
        child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child:
            Column(children: [
              Text('Test!'),
            ],)),
      );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [

        Positioned.fill(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                /// I WANT TO REMOVE THE OVERLAY HERE
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            )
        ),

        theDropDown()

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

As I understand it, the overlay must be removed via a `.remove()` call, but since the overlay is all housed within a StatefulWidget, how can I make a .remove call on the overlay when it was opened outside of the StateWidget?

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this example I created for you

```dart
          OverlayState? _overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
          OverlayEntry? _overlayEntry;
          _overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return ShowNotificationIcon(entry: _overlayEntry);
            },
          );
          _overlayState?.insert(_overlayEntry);
```

```dart
class ShowNotificationIcon extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
final OverlayEntry? entry;
  const ShowNotificationIcon({Key? key, this.entry}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShowNotificationIconState createState() => _ShowNotificationIconState();
}

class _ShowNotificationIconState extends ConsumerState<ShowNotificationIcon> {

  Positioned theDropDown(){
    return
      Positioned(
        top: 50.0,
        left: 50.0,
        child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child:
            Column(children: [
              Text('Test!'),
            ],)),
      );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                if (widget.entry != null){
                  widget.entry.remove();
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            )
        ),

        theDropDown()

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Im getting the following error: ` The getter '_overlayEntry' isn't defined for the class`.  But then I added a var _overlayEntry; before the declaration and it works.  Brilliant. Never thought you could reference itself when making the builder.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here, A sample Toast class. I use close button in overlay. You can use similarly.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppDialogs {
  static final AppDialogs _instance = AppDialogs.internal();

  AppDialogs.internal();

  factory AppDialogs() => _instance;


  static void appToast(
    BuildContext context, {
    required Widget title,
    Widget? description,
    Icon? toastIcon,
    Color? toastColor,
    double? height,
    double? width,
    bool dismissibleToast = true,
  }) async {
    final OverlayState? overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    late OverlayEntry overlayEntry;
    overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (content) => Positioned(
          height: height ?? 80,
          width: width ?? 200,
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Card(
              borderOnForeground: true,
              elevation: 10,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    tileColor: toastColor,
                    title: title,
                    subtitle: description,
                    leading: toastIcon,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () => closeOverlay(overlayEntry),
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          size: 14,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ))),
    );
    overlayState!.insert(overlayEntry);
  }

  static void closeOverlay(OverlayEntry overlayEntry) {
    {
      overlayEntry.remove();
    }
  }
}

class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextButton(
            child: Text("Login"),
            onPressed: (() {
              AppDialogs.appToast(context, title: Text("Toast"));
            }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```